# How can I save text fields with an image and/or video in Android?

Tags: android, image, video, gallery

I have a form for individuals to fill out (a couple of text fields) that they then should be able to attach picture(s) or video(s) to, save and view in a gallery at a later date. I have the form, video and camera and image/video gallery features working but I need to know the best approach for saving these files together so that they can be viewed or sent together. This is way too much code to post, so if you need to see any of the code, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [sqlite database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db). In each row have the following columns:

```
TextField1    |     TextField2     |      TextField3     | File path to image  |   File path to video
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! Although, obviously, I am not familiar with this technology and, thus, I have a lot of learning to do!

Comment: You're welcome! If you found my answer helpful, would you mind accepting the answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it?

Comment: Sorry it took so long! I only recently earned those privileges. :-P